# Access a variable named as its type c#

Tags: c#, variables, naming, ambiguity

In the following example code:

```
public class Foo
{
    public struct Data
    {
        public int val;
    }

    public Data Data

    void method(Foo foo)
    {
        foo.Data.val = 10;
    }
}
```

The previous example causes the following error:

Error 3 Ambiguity between 'Foo.Data' and 'Foo.Data'

Any idea how to fix this error without having to rename the member variable? Since I'm accessing 'Data' through an object instance, then it sounds logical to me that the compiler picks the 'Data' member variable instead of the 'Data' type.

Comment: That's not your only problem.  `The type 'UserQuery.Foo' already contains a definition for 'Data'`

Comment: The program you've posted doesn't produce the error you describe.

Comment: @EricLippert: It does when I test it, although I needed to add the terminating `;` after the field declaration.

Comment: The error is really `"The type 'Demo.Foo' already contains a definition for 'Data'"`

Comment: @EricLippert: On further thought, yes, it can.  `class X { class Y { public static int z; } int z; X Y; }`  Then, `Y.z` could be the static field in `Y` or the instance field of the `X` field.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs, along with a second, more-obvious, error, because they both have the same fully-qualified name – they're both members of `Foo`.

If you move the struct outside the class, it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot do this other than by moving the nested struct outside (or by renaming the property, which you explicitly excluded):

```
public struct Data
{
    public int val;
}

public class Foo
{
    public Data Data;

    void method(Foo foo)
    {
        foo.Data.val = 10;
    }
}
```

If you want to keep `struct Data` more obviously related to `Foo` you could put them both in a nested namespace:

```
namespace FooThings
{
    public struct Data
    {
        public int val;
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public Data Data;

        void method(Foo foo)
        {
            foo.Data.val = 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The actual error from your OP was `"The type 'Demo.Foo' already contains a definition for 'Data'"` (after fixing the missing ";").

Answer (score 0):

change

```
public Data Data;
```

to

```
public Data data;
```

and then

```
void method(Foo foo)
{
    foo.data.val = 10;
}
```